# Limit of the sequence by recurrence of mean of the last two values.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, recurrence-relations

The sequence is defined by recurrence: $x_1=1$, $x_2=2$
\begin{equation}
x_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2}(x_{n}+x_{n-1})
\end{equation}
It is asked to calculate the limit.
I have seen that the sequence is bounded by 1 and 2.
On the other hand, I have seen that the sequence of the pairs, $x_{2n}$, is decreasing and the sequence of the odd, $x_{2n-1}$, is increasing. Therefore both are convergent.
I have seen that both limits are equal, therefore the original sequence is convergent with the same limit.

But I won't be able to prove what the limit is.

Comment: Did you solve the characteristic equation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x_{n+2}$ is the middle of $[x_n,x_{n+1}]$, therefore the distance between $x_n$ and $x_{n+1}$ is divided by $2$ at each iteration, namely
$$ \frac{x_{n+2}-x_{n+1}}{2}=\frac{x_{n+1}+x_n-2x_{n+1}}{4}=-\frac{1}{2}\frac{x_{n+1}-x_n}{2} $$
(there is a $-$ because $(x_{2n})$ and $(x_{2n+1})$ are of opposite monotony). Therefore
$$ \frac{x_{n+1}-x_n}{2}=\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-1}\frac{x_2-x_1}{2}=\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2^n} $$
Thus $x_{n+1}-x_n=\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2^{n-1}}$, summing this gives that
$$ x_n=x_1+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(x_{k+1}-x_k)=1-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k-1}=1+\frac{1-(-1/2)^{n-1}}{1+1/2}=1+2\frac{1-(1/2)^{n-1}}{3} $$
Therefore $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty}x_n=\frac{5}{3}$ (you could also solve the characterisic equation of $(x_n)$ and do the standard calculations.)