# What is the limit of x(1)=0, x(2)=1, x(n) = (x(n-1)+x(n-2))/2

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have the first few terms of the sequence: 0, 1, 1/2, 3/4, 5/8, 11/16, 21/32, and 43/64. The odd index is monotonic increasing while the even index is monotonic decreasing. I know that it’s convergent. I am considering x(n)-x(n-1) => (x(n-1) + x(n-2))/2 - x(n-1) => (x(n-2)-x(n-1), but I’m not sure where to go from there.

Comment: See [Limit of the sequence by recurrence of mean of the last two values](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4322041/limit-of-the-sequence-by-recurrence-of-mean-of-the-last-two-values).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please edit and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to properly format math expressions.